# Uploading a WP image causes wp_remote_post associated with form to fail

Tags: php, wordpress, connection-timeout

My wp application uses a registration form to upload an image (among other data).

I also use after-create and after-update hooks to add the user's email to a constant contact list via `wp_remote_post`.

It is possible to submit/update the form without an image. In that case, the user is added to the constant contact lists.

However, when an image is uploaded with the form, the `wp_remote_post` returns an

> error: http request failed: Couldn't resolve host
>   'visitor2.constantcontact.com'

I am looking for suggestions about how to avoid this connection conflict. As far as I can see, `wp_remote_post` does not have a "retries" argument. Setting timeout to 1200 has no effect.

I'm not clear on what the redirect and blocking arguments do, although changing them also seems to have no effect. Setting form to block ajax processing also has no effect.

Do I try to run this in a new thread???